# Parse session disappears while signup an anonymous user on android

Tags: android, session, parse-platform

Followed by Parse doc, I created an anonymous user while app is first launched.

```
...
Parse.initialize(this, APPLICATION_ID, CLIENT_KEY);
ParseUser.enableRevocableSessionInBackground();
if (ParseUser.getCurrentUser() == null) {
        ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();
        ParseUser.getCurrentUser().increment("RunCount");
        ParseUser.getCurrentUser().saveInBackground();
}
```

In the parse core, it shows that a new "User" and "Session" row is successfully added.

```
...
ParseUser.getCurrentUser().setUsername("Leo");
ParseUser.getCurrentUser().setPassword("sasami");
ParseUser.getCurrentUser().signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
            ...
            }
        }
...
```

Then after I calling the "signUpInBackground" method, I found the just-added User row has been updated, **but the just-added Session row was disappear.** And consequently the user-related query and execution always returns an

> com.parse.ParseRequest$ParseRequestException: invalid session token

P.S.
It doesn't matter if signup successfully or returned error. The Session row disappears anyway.

Comment: Just a suggestion; Parse is shutting down. Beginning of next year all servers will be gone.

Comment: Why do you create anonymous user when you are then signing him up? Anonymous user should be used only if you will not do "standard" authentication...

Comment: @ChadBingham Thank you for reminder. Our team is also exploring the AWS server currently. Just want to stay in Parse for couple month temporarily.

Comment: @MazelTov You're right. However, on our design, we'd like to assign an anonymous whenever user open the app. Then if they prefer to sign up later, we'll share the bonus in app and keep them tracking previous orders. Thus, we need to sign up an anonymous account.

Comment: I would suggest that you signup every anonymous user with his UUID and some predefined password and then you can just create another user with signup function and "transfer" all his stuff with cloud code